# view not created for fragment of viewpager inside recyclerview

Tags: kotlin, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager, exoplayer2.x

I want to make Home screen like Instagram where video will play/pause on horizontal and vertical scrolling.

For that I am using fragment inside viewpager and viewpager inside recyclerview for achieving horizontal and vertical scrolling.

Issue is that for second item of recyclerview view of fragment is not created.

can anyone help me to achieve this functionality.

Thanks in advance.

## Below is the adapter class of recyclerview.

```
class DashboardFeedsAdapterNew(
    private val mContext: Context, var mList: ArrayList<PostListModel.PostListData>,
    private val viewHolderClicks: ViewHolderClicks,
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {
    var mInflater: LayoutInflater =
        mContext.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
    var mActivePage = 0
    private var isLoadingAdded = false

    val LOADING_TYPE = 0
    val POST_TYPE = 1
    val STORY_TYPE = 2

    fun getList(): ArrayList<PostListModel.PostListData> {
        return mList
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(
        parent: ViewGroup,
        viewType: Int
    ): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        when (viewType) {
          
            POST_TYPE -> {
                val v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                    .inflate(R.layout.raw_feed, parent, false)
                return PostViewHolder(v)
            }
            
        }
        val v =
            mInflater.inflate(R.layout.raw_feed, parent, false)
        return PostViewHolder(
            v
        )
    }

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        if(position == mList.size -1 && isLoadingAdded) {
            return LOADING_TYPE
        } else {
            /*if ((position + 1) % 5 == 0) {
                return STORY_TYPE
            }*/
            return POST_TYPE
        }
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(
        holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
        position: Int
    ) {
        val model = mList[holder.adapterPosition]
         if (holder is PostViewHolder) {
            //post type
            try {
                if (model.files.isNotEmpty()) {
                    setupViewpager(holder, model)
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
    }

    private fun setupViewpager(binding: PostViewHolder, model: PostListModel.PostListData) {

        binding.vpAttachment.adapter =  ViewPagerAdapter((activityContext() as AppCompatActivity).supportFragmentManager,model)

        binding.vpAttachment.addOnPageChangeListener(object : ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
            override fun onPageScrolled(
                position: Int,
                positionOffset: Float,
                positionOffsetPixels: Int
            ) {
                mActivePage = binding.vpAttachment.currentItem
            }

            override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
            }

            override fun onPageScrollStateChanged(state: Int) {}
        })
    }

   

    inner class ViewPagerAdapter(fm: FragmentManager, val mData: PostListModel.PostListData) :
        FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fm, BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT ) { //FragmentPagerAdapter

        private val mFragmentList = java.util.ArrayList<Fragment>()
        private val mFragmentTitleList = java.util.ArrayList<String>()

        fun addFragment(fragment: Fragment, title: String) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment)
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title)
        }

        //added this metod to update fragment after edit post
        override fun getItemPosition(`object`: Any): Int {
            return POSITION_NONE
        }

        override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
            mData.files[position].position = position
            return PostMediaPreviewPageFragment.newInstance(position,mData.id, mData.files[position])
        }

        override fun getCount(): Int {
            return mData.files.size
        }

        override fun getPageTitle(position: Int): CharSequence? {
            return mFragmentTitleList[position]
        }
    }
 
    private fun activityContext(): Context {
        val context = mContext
        return context
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return mList.size
    }

    inner class ViewMoreViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val progressBar: ProgressBar = itemView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar)
    }

    inner class PostViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val imgAvatar: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgAvatar)
        val tvUserName: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvUserName)
        val vpAttachment: ViewPager = itemView.findViewById(R.id.vpAttachment)
//        val indicator: IndicatorView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.indicator)
        val imgFeed: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgFeed)
        val imgPlay: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgPlay)
        val tvAttachmentCount: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvAttachmentCount)
        val tvFeedTitle: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvFeedTitle)
        val tvLocation: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvLocation)
        val tvViewCount: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvViewCount)
        val imgLike: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgLike)
        val tvLikeCount: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvLikeCount)
        val lnComment: LinearLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.lnComment)
        val tvCommentCount: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvCommentCount)
        val btnTakeAction: Button = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnTakeAction)
    }

    inner class StoryViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val rvStory: RecyclerView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rvStory)
        val viewPager: ViewPager2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.vpStory)
        val indicator: CircleIndicator2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.indicator)
    }

    interface ViewHolderClicks {
        fun onUserClick(model: PostListModel.PostListData, position: Int)
        fun onImageClick(model: PostListModel.PostListData, position: Int)
        fun onLikeClick(model: PostListModel.PostListData, position: Int)
        fun onLikeCountClick(model: PostListModel.PostListData, position: Int)
        fun onCommentClick(model: PostListModel.PostListData, position: Int)
        fun onTakeActionClick(model: PostListModel.PostListData, position: Int)
    }
}
```